# importing a module when the module name is in a variable

Tags: python

I have some code like:

```
data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))]
hello = data_files[0]
modulename = hello[0].split(".")[0]

import modulename
```

The goal is to get the name of a file from a directory as a string, pass it to some other code, and then import the module *whose name is stored in the variable name*.

However, in my code attempt, the `modulename` in `import modulename` is treated as the name of the module to import, rather than the string stored in that variable.

How can I get the effect that I want instead?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You want the built in [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function

```
new_module = __import__(modulename)
```

Comment: After the code you've written runs, what is stored in `new_module`?  Is it how I now refer to `modulename`, the same way that `np` refers to `numpy` after running `import numpy as np`?

Comment: I have the same question. Suppose new_module is a package (in folder modulename) and it has file foo.py inside. I don't think you can call new_module.foo.somefunction(), it will say there is no module foo.

Comment: IIRC, I believe that `foo = __import__('foo')` should be equivalent to `import foo`.  `bar = `__import__('foo')` is the same as `import foo as bar`, etc.  If you're working with a package, the package's `__init__.py` will be imported as per usual.  e.g. `__import__('numpy').core` gives you the numpy core subpackage since numpy's `__init__.py` imports `numpy.core`.

Comment: When I imported a submodule, I still needed to access it with the full path - so it wasn't good enough for me. E.g. m = __import__("a.b.c"), and then I'd need to reference c as m.b.c.

Answer (score 48):

importlib is probably the way to go.  The documentation on it is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html).  It's generally preferred over `__import__` for [most uses.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

In your case, you would use:

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module(module_name, package=None)
```

Comment: Use [`imp.load_source(..)` from the `imp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) if you don't know the path to the module `.py` file.

Comment: How do I do a `from` import with multiple selections with this. Like `from configparser import ConfigParser, NoSectionError`? And `from foo import *`?

Comment: @576i if you've imported configparser as module, you can provide the names with `ConfigParser = configparser.ConfigParser` and so on. `import *` is mischief and I won't encourage it.