# How to import the lookup.py files dynamically during the runtime based on a condition?

Tags: python

There is path 'lookup/lookup_files' where my lookup files are present. The name of the files are standardized as productname1_lookup.py, productname2_lookup.py, productname3_lookup.py and so on.
Now instead of importing all the files normally I am wanting to import and load the lookup file based on the product name dynamically during the run-time itself.
Can anyone please help me to achieve this. I lised down all the files in the given path by using os.listdir but I am unable to understand how I could import.
Any help would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your module name is stored in a variable `modulename` during runtime. Example

```
new_module = __import__(modulename)
```

Reference: [importing a module when the module name is in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598035/importing-a-module-when-the-module-name-is-in-a-variable)