# How do I import variables from a file based on a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make different language files for my script, and the way I intended to set this up (after some googling) is that based on user's choice, a `.py` file (`%cwd%\locale\en.py`, `%cwd%\locale\ru.py` etc) with all strings saved as variables is imported using `importlib.import_module`, and all text after that is formatted with f-strings using variables from the imported file.

I've tried providing strings with the relative name such as `locale.en` (as I would in a normal import) and the full path acquired using `str(Path(Path.cwd() / 'locale' / 'en.py'))` (`print` showed that the directory is acquired correctly), and in both cases I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I kinda sorta understand why I would get it using the relative name, but how come the full path is not enough? I keep finding answers mentioning that `__init__.py` is required in the `locale` folder, but I also find [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598111/7971750) that make no mention of it.

Not sure if it's relevant, but in the full path's `ModuleNotFoundError` every backslash is doubled (e.g. `C:\\Script\\locale\\en`)

Comment: To do this properly, have you considered gettext? https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html

Comment: it sounds like you're giving a path like '/path/to/module' to importlib.import_module?  I believe it takes a dotted module path, like an import statement - importlib.import_module('relative.module.path').  An example of what you're actually doing in your code would be helpful.

Comment: Doing this by dynamic imports sounds doable but difficult.  I agree with @deceze that `gettext` is the better option.  If for some reason that doesn't work, putting the data into CSVs seems like a better option than hardcoding it in `.py` files.

Comment: `gettext` has been around for years and is fully debugged. Don't reinvent the wheel…

Comment: @zyd I tried both (`importlib.import_module('locale.en')`, `importlib.import_module('path/locale/en.py')`) with both producing `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: I didn't know about `gettext`, will try it out. Thanks to everyone who mentioned it.