# Command line argument in python to run one of two scripts

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, sys

My package has the following structure:

```
mypackage
|-__main__.py
|-__init__.py
|-model
  |-__init__.py
  |-modelfile.py
|-simulation
  |-sim1.py
  |-sim2.py
```

The content of the file `__main__.py` is

```
from mypackage.simulation import sim1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sim1
```

So that when I execute `python -m mypackage`, the script `sim1.py` runs.
Now I would like to add an argument to the command line, so that `python -m mypackage sim1` runs `sim1.py` and  `python -m mypackage sim2` runs `sim2.py`.

I've tried the follwing:

```
import sys
from mypackage.simulation import sim1,sim2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv:
        arg
```

But it runs boths scripts instead of the one passed in argument.

In `sim1.py` and `sim2.py` I have the following code

```
from mypackage.model import modelfile

print('modelfile.ModelClass.someattr')
```

Comment: do you have " if __name__ == '__main__' " in sim1.py and sim2.py as well? If you do not this behaviour is expected as you are importing both sim1.py and sim2.py

Comment: I don't. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: can you show what code you have in `sim1` and `sim2`.

Comment: @nobleknight I've added in my post the code contained in sim1 and sim2

Comment: it's just one line. show rest of code.

Comment: @nobleknight The rest of code isn't relevant to the problem, I added an example.

Comment: @DeepNet see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `__import__` with the module name as parameter, e.g.:

```
new_module = __import__(arg)
```

in your loop.

So, for example, you have your main program named `example.py`:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        module=__import__(arg)
        print(arg, module.foo(1))
```

Note that `sys.argv[0]` contains the program name.

You have your `sim1.py`:

```
print('sim1')

def foo(n):
    return n+1
```

and your `sim2.py`:

```
print('sim2')

def foo(n):
    return n+2
```

then you can call

```
python example.py sim1 sim2
```

output:

```
sim1
sim1 2
sim2
sim2 3
```

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv:
        __import__(arg)` and calling `python -m mypackage sim1` returns a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: You have to take about the parameters, because the first parameter is the program name, so you should skip that. I include this in more detail in the answare.

Comment: This still produces a `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: You need to assign the result of `__import__` to the global name space to have the symbol name exposed as a module. See my answer for an example.  The code in this answer simply assigns it to `new_module`, or, in later examples, simply discards it. But if all the useful action happens when you `import`, being able to refer to the module by its original name seems less important anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have you files with following content.

---

**`sim1.py`**

```py
def simulation1():
    print("This is simulation 1")

simulation1()
```

**`main.py`**

```py
import sim1

sim1.simulation1()
```

**`output`**

```sh
This is simulation 1
This is simulation 1
```

When you import `sim1` into `main.py` and calls its function `simulation1`, then `This is simulation 1` gets printed 2 times.
Because, `simulation1` is called inside `sim1.py` and also in `main.py`.

If you want to run that function in `sim1.py`, but don't want to run when `sim1` is imported, then you can place it inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

---

**`sim1.py`**

```py
def simulation1():
    print("This is simulation 1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    simulation1()
```

**`main.py`**

```py
import sim1

sim1.simulation1()
```

**`output`**

```sh
This is simulation 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do what you want it to do.  Just `sim1` doesn't actually call the function; the syntax to do that is `sim1()`.

You *could* make your Python script evaluate random strings from the command line as Python expressions, but that's really not a secure or elegant way to solve this.  Instead, have the strings map to internal functions, which may or may not have the same name. For example,

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
     import sys
     for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
         if arg == 'sim1':
            sim1()
         if arg == 'mustard':
            sim2()
         if arg == 'ketchup':
            sim3(sausages=2, cucumber=user in cucumberlovers)
         else:
            raise ValueError('Anguish! Don\'t know how to handle %s' % arg)
```

As this should hopefully illustrate, the symbol you accept on the command line does not need to correspond to the name of the function you want to run.  If you *want* that to be the case, you can simplify this to use a dictionary:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    d = {fun.__name__: fun for fun in (sim1, sim2)}
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg in d:
            d[arg]()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Anguish! etc')
```

What's perhaps important to note here is that you select exactly which Python symbols you want to give the user access to from the command line, and allow no others to leak through.  That would be a security problem (think what would happen if someone passed in `'import shutil; shutil.rmtree("/")'` as the argument to run). This is similar in spirit to the many, many reasons to avoid `eval`, which you will find are easy to google (and you probably should if this is unfamiliar to you).

If `sim1` is a module name you want to *import* only when the user specifically requests it, that's not hard to do either; see [importing a module when the module name is in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598035/importing-a-module-when-the-module-name-is-in-a-variable) but then you can't `import` it earlier on in the script.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    modules = ['sim1', 'sim2']
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg in modules:
            globals()[arg] = __import__(arg)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Anguish! etc')
```

But generally speaking, modules should probably only define functions, and leave it to the caller to decide if and when to run them at some time after they `import` the module.

Perhaps tangentially look into third-party libraries like `click` which easily allow you to expose selected functions as "subcommands" of your Python script, vaguely similarly to how `git` has subcommands `init`, `log`, etc.

Comment: I am not sure why you're assuming `sim1` to be a function, to me `sim1.py` it is simply a module without a `sim1()` function in it

Comment: Oh, right, if your packages run some code immediately when you `import` them, that explains your arrangement; but then you have to `import` the package you want only when you have decided which one you want.  I'll add a brief update to cover this scenario. (Then @keyboarder's answer is the one you need, though they should probably explain in more detail why.)