# Function to import modules from a list

Tags: python, import

My goal is to have a function with a list of strings as input and import those modules I want for my code.

Example:

```
list_of_modules = ['module1', 'module2']

def importer(list_of_modules):
    for module in list_of_modules:
        if module == 'module1':
            from package.package2.module1 import function1
        if module == 'module2':
            from package.package2.module2 import function1
        if module == 'module3':
            from package.package2.module3 import function1
```

I have tried this solution and it seems like the modules are not imported. I have also tried using **import** builtin function, but nothing.

My real example was:

```
def importer(modules):
    for value in modules:
        if value == "ble_connection":
            from top_app.module.connection.test_connectivity import connection1
        if value == "switch_connection":
            from top_app.module.connection.test_connectivity import connection2
```

I have to add that I am using pytest for running the tests from the general conftest file and this one calls this importer function during the pytest_configure hook which is right after the discovery hook.

Do you have any solution for this?

thanks

Comment: This should work, albeit that function1 will be overwritten.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `importlib` module.

Comment: Can you add your attempt of using `__import__`?

Comment: How have you tested that it's not working? Please show us your testing code. For example, a `print(function1)` line after the for loop would be enough.

Comment: I have tried __import__ but it looks like nothing is being imported

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing a module when the module name is in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598035/importing-a-module-when-the-module-name-is-in-a-variable)

Comment: I guess that works for something like importing mathplotlib or scipy but I want to import custom packages like mypackage.module1.module2. I does not work for my case, or it seems not to be working

Comment: If it works for standard packages, but not for your own custom packages, than it's likely the problem is with the structure of your package, and not with the import itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer 976...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exec` for this purpose:

```py
list_of_modules = ['module1', 'module2']
for module in list_of_modules:
    exec('package.package2.{} import function1'.format(module))
```

but as someone commented on your OP, `function1` will be overwritten doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I finally ended up using the pytest_collection_modifyitems hook from pytest. It works pretty well. Though it just allow you to deactivate certain test functions but packages are imported anyway.