# Module installed but not imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller, libraries

I’m trying to install and import the modules who are missing in a python script before it shows error.

```
try: 
     import matplotlib 
     import numpy
except ImportError as e:
     import os 
     module = e.name 
     os.system(‘pip install ‘+ module)
     import module
```

The errors I get : `ModuleNotFound : No module named “matplotlib”`

`import module ModuleNotFoundError: No module named “module”`
Although the module gets installed correctly, when I rerun it again, the script recognizes the installed modules and works fine. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: `Import` is not a valid python statement. do you mean `import`?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yes that's what I meant, thanks for noticing it

Comment: Ok, now it gives the error `SyntaxError: invalid character '‘' (U+2018)` You are using strange quotes, you should use `'` or `"`

Comment: and then take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598035/importing-a-module-when-the-module-name-is-in-a-variable  You cannot do `import module` you need to use __import__

Comment: Thanks I solved it with importlib! One more question I'm trying to write all the missing in a file and install them fromt ehre, but somehow only the first missing module gets wrriten. 
The code goes like 
```try: 
     import matplotlib 
     import numpy
except ImportError as e:
     with open("file.txt", "a+") as f:
            f.write(e.name)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these functions will solve it. I use importlib because if you try to import like *import module* python sees it like there is a module named module not matplotlib. So, you need to use *importlib.import_module()* to overcome this situation.

```
import os
import sys


def library_installer(name):
    """
    Install a library from the pip package manager.
    """
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", name])

def library_importer(name):
    """
    Import a library from the pip package manager.
    """
    import importlib
    return importlib.import_module(name)

try:
    import e

except ImportError as x:
    library_installer(x.name)
    library_installer(x.name)
```

Here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) for importlib if you want.

Comment: One more question I'm trying to write all the missing in a file and install them fromt ehre, but somehow only the first missing module gets wrriten. 
The code goes like 
```try: 
     import matplotlib 
     import numpy
except ImportError as e:
     with open("file.txt", "a+") as f:
            f.write(e.name)```

Comment: Can you open another question? I don't want to break format of Q&A system and I can easily show and explain the code you want. @user14635293