# Run a file in the same folder, using a variable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to run an other file in the same folder, by using a variable as the name of the file. But it always tells me, that its invalid.

```
name = File

import name
```

What do i have to add, that it detects, that this is a variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing a module when the module name is in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598035/importing-a-module-when-the-module-name-is-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a py file and the file in the same directory. Just `import file`

or if it is in subdirectory `import folder.file`

or if you just want to import a variable or a function `from file import  some_variable` or `from folder.file import some_variable`

or import everything `from file import *`

If your file not a py file you have to open the file according to file type. You can not use `import`